# Why doesn't the "View all badges" link appear on the user profile page for some users?

Tags: bug, badges

On my user page's profile tab, I am able to see a link at the bottom that says "View all badges", similar to the "View all questions and answers" link above it.

[image: View all badges on my profile]

However, for some users that have **at least 4 unique bronze badges**, there is no link to see their badges, despite the fact that I can't see all their badges in that section. Examples of users who don't have a link there:

- [beyowolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442445/beyowulf), 1 gold, 1 silver, 7 bronze
- [Bugra Baskaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576779/bugra-baskaya), 1 silver, 8 bronze
- [Szilard Magyar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4811651/szilard-magyar), 1 silver, 7 bronze
- [Son Nguyen Thanh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385211/son-nguyen-thanh), 9 bronze
- [Bablu Dutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680953/bablu-dutt), 8 bronze
- [Dazed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3820556/dazed), 7 bronze
- [brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4383153/brad), 6 bronze
- [user2922825](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2922825/user2922825), 5 bronze
- [Niko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1474790/niko), 4 bronze

Users who *do* have a link there, despite having similar numbers to (and in some cases the same as) those above:

- [anbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774831/anbuf), 2 silver, 7 bronze
- [jharley1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350990/jharley1), 1 silver, 8 bronze
- [vladeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193202/vladeck), 1 silver, 7 bronze
- [kartheek desineedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1456773/kartheek-desineedi), 1 silver, 6 bronze
- [Rakhitha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887286/rakhitha), 9 bronze
- [freieschaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084293/freieschaf), 8 bronze
- [Carson Morrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673365/carson-morrow), 7 bronze

Interestingly, [user2344442](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2344442/user2344442) has the link there despite the fact that they only have 3 *unique* badges out of 4 total (all bronze), so you are able to "see all badges" without even clicking on the link. And further still, [user1198014](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198014/user1198014) has 1 "Notable Question" and 2 "Popular Question" badges, and that's it, but still has the link there.

---

Are these oddities by design? It seems kind of arbitrary.

---

**Edit:** I can go through the Activity tab and click "Badges" or append `&tab=badges` to the URL to get to see the badges for any users; I'm more wondering why this link's presence seems to be so inconsistent.

Comment: They're vampires - their badges cannot be reflected.

Comment: Odd indeed. Of course there's nothing stopping you making the link yourself, just append `?tab=badges` to the any of the profile links above  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/5442445/beyowulf?tab=badges

Comment: (or click activity and go to badges)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to add as a note to my question that you can obviously go through the activity tab and click "Badges" to see them all because I was too focused on the weirdness of this specific link. I'll add that to my question now.

Comment: Your list of users without that link is much shorter now. I observed this issue as well. I normally see that there is a small gap for 4 to 9 total badges where the link isn't displayed but should. Maybe there is another issue because the total amount of badges doesn't explain what we see in [this user profile with 1+8=9 badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1456773/kartheek-desineedi). Can badges be retracted?

Answer (score 10):

All users who do have the link you're talking about have at least one non-unique badge:

> [image]

All the others have *only unique* badges. Why exactly this fact is used to show the link is beyond me. So it probably needs fixing:

- Show the link if a badge was awarded twice or more (like it is now) *or*
- Show the link if there are at least 4 unique badges in one of the categories.

Comment: I think it would be easier to just always show the link, regardless of the number of badges. That would simplify the code and present a more consistent user interface.